# "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." while using redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm following a tutorial from this link: http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/react-redux-tutorial-part-ii-react-router-and-container-components/
But when the `handleSubmit()` function is fired i get an error:

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

But i'm using redux-thunk as middleware. Is there something missing?
I'm using Antd as UI framework.

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';  
import {connect} from 'react-redux';  
import * as sessionActions from './actions/sessionActions';

const FormItem = Form.Item;

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {credentials: {username: '', password: ''}};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    const credentials = this.state.credentials;
    credentials[field] = event.target.value;;
    return this.setState({credentials: credentials});
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        //console.log(this.props.actions);
        this.props.actions.logInUser(this.state.credentials);
      }
    });
  }


  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'username missing!' }],
          })(
          <Input 
              name="username"
              value={this.state.credentials.username} 
              prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} 
              placeholder="Username o email"
              onChange={this.onChange}/>
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Password missing!' }],
          })(
          <Input 
            name="password"
            value={this.state.credentials.password}
            prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} 
            type="password" 
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={this.onChange}/>
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
              valuePropName: 'checked',
              initialValue: false,
            })(
              <Checkbox>Ricordami</Checkbox>
            )}
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
          Log in
          </Button>
        </FormItem>
        </Form>
    );
  }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {  
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(sessionActions, dispatch)
  };
}


export default compose(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps), Form.create())(Login);
```

**sessionReducer.js**

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';  
import initialState from './initialState';  

export default function sessionReducer(state = initialState.session, action) {  
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS:
      this.context.history.push('/')
      return !!sessionStorage.jwt
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

**sessionActions.js**

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';  
import sessionApi from '../api/sessionApi';

export function loginSuccess() {  
  return {type: types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS}
}

export function logInUser(credentials) {  
  return function(dispatch) {
    return sessionApi.login(credentials).then(response => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', response.jwt);
      dispatch(loginSuccess());
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

**sessionApi.js (login)**

```
import React from 'react'

var axios = require('axios');
var qs = require('qs');

class SessionApi {  

  static login(credentials){
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', qs.stringify({auth: credentials}))
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      }),
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      };
  }
}
```

**Store configuration**

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger'

export default function configureStore() {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, logger),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks to me that your store setup is not applying correctly the middlewares. Try the following approach to crete the store.

```
const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware, logger];

const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);
```

With this approach, the `composeEnhancers` function will use `compose` in production or the one from devtools in development. Then your middlewares should work.